# Python index function inquiry

Tags: python, list, indexing

If I have a `name = 'Peter Piper Picker'` and I want my function to selective isolate 'Picker', what would I have to do? I don't mean like `name[12:]`, but like where it picks out where the last space before the end of the name is and starts substring-ing from there? I know index function has two additional parameters, but I don't know how they can be applied properly in this setting I was thinking `name[' ', name.split(len(name.split()-1)), name[len(name)-1]]`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) method of `str`.

```
name = 'Peter Piper Picker' 
# name.split() will return a list ['Peter', 'Piper', 'Picker'], we need its last element   
ret = name.split()[-1]
```

Then `ret` is `'Picker'`.

Answer (score 4):

You could also do:

```
name = 'Peter Piper Picker'
name.rsplit(" ",1)[1]
'Picker'
```

When using `rsplit` you will get the following output:

```
name.rsplit(" ",1)
['Peter Piper', 'Picker']
```

**Process:**

You are splitting from the right and you are splitting once using " " and getting the second element

**Information:**

For more on [`rsplit` look into rsplit official document](http://python-reference.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/str/rsplit.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> name = 'Peter Piper Picker'
>>> a = name.split()
>>> a[len(a)-1]
'Picker'
```

Answer (score 1):

The cryptic way:

```
>>> name[[i for i, c in enumerate(name) if c == ' '][-1]+1:]
'Picker'
```

- `[i for i, c in enumerate(name) if c == ' ']` - this will get you all the indexes where there is a space (`' '`) in your string
- `[i for i, c in enumerate(name) if c == ' '][-1]` - this will get you the index of the last space
- `[i for i, c in enumerate(name) if c == ' '][-1]+1` - this one is the position where you desired name part starts

And finally you slice your `name`.